# Standard, but specific "End With without With" Compile error

Tags: excel, vba

Given an Standard compile error "End WIth without With" msgbox.
I have just started vba coding. Pls give some instruction to let me step forward. (As the code has been inserted, tabulators got wrong. Do not bother with that.)

I have checked IF statements, object correctness, included loops.

```
'*2/B. - Generate template based new excel file and fill up cells with data of document attributes*
    For n = 1 To documentCount
    Dim strTemplate As String: strTemplate = "C:\Users\C3642\Desktop\FU5504-Elfogadhatosagi_Nyilatkozat_formanyomtatvany\PA2-FU-5504-NY-01_v2.xlsx"
    Set outXl = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strTemplate, True)
    Set outXl = ActiveWorkbook
    With outXl.Worksheets(1)
    .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\C3642\Desktop\FU5504-Elfogadhatosagi_Nyilatkozat_formanyomtatvany\" & docCode(n) & "_" & docResponsible(n) & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    .Cells(5, 4).Value = docName(n)
    .Cells(6, 4).Value = docCode(n)
    '.Cells(6, 13).Value = docRevision(n) <- nincs hozzá adat :(
    .Cells(14, 4).Value = docResponsible(n)
    If departmentHead(n) = "Name1" Then
            .Cells(14, 7).Value = "VIO"
            .Cells(31, 7).Value = "VIO"
            .Cells(31, 4).Value = departmentHead(n)
    If departmentHead(n) = "Name2" Then
            .Cells(14, 7).Value = "ITO"
            .Cells(31, 7).Value = "ITO"
            .Cells(31, 4).Value = departmentHead(n)
    If departmentHead(n) = "Name3" Then
            .Cells(14, 7).Value = "VSKO"
            .Cells(31, 7).Value = "VSKO"
            .Cells(31, 4).Value = departmentHead(n)
    If departmentHead(n) = "Name4" Then
            .Cells(14, 7).Value = "AMO"
            .Cells(31, 7).Value = "AMO"
            .Cells(31, 4).Value = departmentHead(n)
    If departmentHead(n) = "Name5" Then
            .Cells(14, 7).Value = "NUO"
            .Cells(31, 7).Value = "NUO"
            .Cells(31, 4).Value = departmentHead(n)
    If departmentHead(n) = "Name6" Then
            .Cells(14, 7).Value = "KGO"
            .Cells(31, 7).Value = "KGO"
            .Cells(31, 4).Value = departmentHead(n)
    If departmentHead(n) = "Name7" Then
            .Cells(14, 7).Value = "PGO"
            .Cells(31, 7).Value = "PGO"
            .Cells(31, 4).Value = departmentHead(n)
    If departmentHead(n) = "Name8" Then
            .Cells(14, 7).Value = "ETO"
            .Cells(31, 7).Value = "ETO"
            .Cells(31, 4).Value = departmentHead(n)
    If departmentHead(n) = "Name9" Then
            .Cells(14, 7).Value = "GMDO"
            .Cells(31, 7).Value = "GMDO"
            .Cells(31, 4).Value = departmentHead(n)
    If departmentHead(n) = "Name10" Then
            .Cells(14, 7).Value = "ABO"
            .Cells(31, 7).Value = "ABO"
            .Cells(31, 4).Value = departmentHead(n)
    Else
            .Cells(14, 7).Value = ""
            .Cells(31, 7).Value = ""
            .Cells(31, 4).Value = ""
    '.Cells(31, 4).Value = supervisorName(n)
    '.Cells(31, 7).Value = supervisorDepartment(n)
    .Cells(33, 4).Value = "Name0"
    Dim innerReviewers() As String: Dim split_ETO_reviewers() As String: Dim split_KGO_reviewers() As String: Dim split_PGO_reviewers() As String: Dim split_NUO_reviewers() As String
    Dim split_AMO_reviewers() As String: Dim split_VSKO_reviewers() As String: Dim split_VIO_reviewers() As String: Dim split_ABO_reviewers() As String: Dim split_ITO_reviewers() As String
    Dim split_UIG_reviewers() As String: Dim split_ENBO_reviewers() As String: Dim split_LETO_reviewers() As String: Dim split_Non_ERBE_reviewers() As String: Dim split_ERBE_reviewers() As String
    innerReviewers() = Split(reviewers(n), ",")
    split_ETO_reviewers() = Split(ETO_reviewers(n), ",")
    split_KGO_reviewers() = Split(KGO_reviewers(n), ",")
    split_PGO_reviewers() = Split(PGO_reviewers(n), ",")
    split_NUO_reviewers() = Split(NUO_reviewers(n), ",")
    split_AMO_reviewers() = Split(AMO_reviewers(n), ",")
    split_VSKO_reviewers() = Split(VSKO_reviewers(n), ",")
    split_VIO_reviewers() = Split(VIO_reviewers(n), ",")
    split_ABO_reviewers() = Split(ABO_reviewers(n), ",")
    split_ITO_reviewers() = Split(ITO_reviewers(n), ",")
    split_UIG_reviewers() = Split(UIG_reviewers(n), ",")
    split_ENBO_reviewers() = Split(ENBO_reviewers(n), ",")
    split_LETO_reviewers() = Split(LETO_reviewers(n), ",")
    split_Non_ERBE_reviewers() = Split(Non_ERBE_reviewers(n), ",")
    split_ERBE_reviewers() = Split(ERBE_reviewers(n), ",")
    reviewersCount = 0
    If IsEmpty(innerReviewers) Or (IsEmpty(innerReviewers) & IsEmpty(split_ETO_reviewers) & IsEmpty(split_KGO_reviewers) & IsEmpty(split_PGO_reviewers) & IsEmpty(split_NUO_reviewers) & IsEmpty(split_AMO_reviewers) & IsEmpty(split_VSKO_reviewers) & IsEmpty(split_VIO_reviewers) & IsEmpty(split_ABO_reviewers) & IsEmpty(split_ITO_reviewers)) Then
        MsgBox "The current document has not been reviewed by colleques! (Archiving function of list of non-reviewed docs is not ready.)", vbOKOnly, "Warning for lacking reviewers!"
    Else
        reviewersCount = UBound(innerReviewers) - LBound(innerReviewers) + 1
        Dim i As Integer
        i = 0
        Do While (i < reviewersCount & i < 12)
            .Cells(15 + i, 4).Value = innerReviewers(i)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        reviewersCount = reviewersCount + UBound(split_ETO_reviewers) - LBound(split_ETO_reviewers) + 1
        Do While (i < (12 - reviewersCount))
            .Cells(15 + i, 4).Value = ETO_reviewers(i)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        reviewersCount = reviewersCount + UBound(split_KGO_reviewers) - LBound(split_KGO_reviewers) + 1
        Do While (i < (12 - reviewersCount))
            .Cells(15 + i, 4).Value = KGO_reviewers(i)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        reviewersCount = reviewersCount + UBound(split_PGO_reviewers) - LBound(split_PGO_reviewers) + 1
        Do While (i < (12 - reviewersCount))
            .Cells(15 + i, 4).Value = PGO_reviewers(i)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        reviewersCount = reviewersCount + UBound(split_NUO_reviewers) - LBound(split_NUO_reviewers) + 1
        Do While (i < (12 - reviewersCount))
            .Cells(15 + i, 4).Value = NUO_reviewers(i)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        reviewersCount = reviewersCount + UBound(split_AMO_reviewers) - LBound(split_AMO_reviewers) + 1
        Do While (i < (12 - reviewersCount))
            .Cells(15 + i, 4).Value = AMO_reviewers(i)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        reviewersCount = reviewersCount + UBound(split_VSKO_reviewers) - LBound(split_VSKO_reviewers) + 1
        Do While (i < (12 - reviewersCount))
            .Cells(15 + i, 4).Value = VSKO_reviewers(i)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        reviewersCount = reviewersCount + UBound(split_VIO_reviewers) - LBound(split_VIO_reviewers) + 1
        Do While (i < (12 - reviewersCount))
            .Cells(15 + i, 4).Value = VIO_reviewers(i)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        reviewersCount = reviewersCount + UBound(split_ABO_reviewers) - LBound(split_ABO_reviewers) + 1
        Do While (i < (12 - reviewersCount))
            .Cells(15 + i, 4).Value = ABO_reviewers(i)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        reviewersCount = reviewersCount + UBound(split_ITO_reviewers) - LBound(split_ITO_reviewers) + 1
        Do While (i < (12 - reviewersCount))
            .Cells(15 + i, 4).Value = ITO_reviewers(i)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        reviewersCount = reviewersCount + UBound(split_UIG_reviewers) - LBound(split_UIG_reviewers) + 1
        Do While (i < (12 - reviewersCount))
            .Cells(15 + i, 4).Value = UIG_reviewers(i)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        reviewersCount = reviewersCount + UBound(split_ENBO_reviewers) - LBound(split_ENBO_reviewers) + 1
        Do While (i < (12 - reviewersCount))
            .Cells(15 + i, 4).Value = ENBO_reviewers(i)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        reviewersCount = reviewersCount + UBound(split_LETO_reviewers) - LBound(split_LETO_reviewers) + 1
        Do While (i < (12 - reviewersCount))
            .Cells(15 + i, 4).Value = LETO_reviewers(i)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        'reviewersCount = reviewersCount + UBound(split_Non_ERBE_reviewers) - LBound(split_Non_ERBE_reviewers) + 1
        'Do While (i < (12 - reviewersCount))
        '     .Cells(15 + i, 4).Value = Non_ERBE_reviewers(i)
        '     i = i + 1
        'Loop
        'reviewersCount = reviewersCount + UBound(split_ERBE_reviewers) - LBound(split_ERBE_reviewers) + 1
        'Do While (i < (12 - reviewersCount))
        '     .Cells(15 + i, 4).Value = ERBE_reviewers(i)
        '     i = i + 1
        'Loop
    End With
    outXl.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Next n
```

Maybe Workbook object are not setted properly (but it is declared in my code).

Comment: your if's need to be ElseIfs after the first and you are missing End Ifs

Answer (score 4):

The error shows up, because there is a `End If` missing everywhere.

E.g.:

```
If departmentHead(n) = "Name3" Then
        .Cells(14, 7).Value = "VSKO"
        .Cells(31, 7).Value = "VSKO"
        .Cells(31, 4).Value = departmentHead(n)
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

It's expecting a bunch of End If or ElseIfs, and not seeing them it's complaining about the first unclosed statement (the with).

For example, fix it to:

```
...
If departmentHead(n) = "Name1" Then
            .Cells(14, 7).Value = "VIO"
            .Cells(31, 7).Value = "VIO"
            .Cells(31, 4).Value = departmentHead(n)
ElseIf departmentHead(n) = "Name2" Then
            .Cells(14, 7).Value = "ITO"
            .Cells(31, 7).Value = "ITO"
            .Cells(31, 4).Value = departmentHead(n)
ElseIf departmentHead(n) = "Name3" Then
            .Cells(14, 7).Value = "VSKO"
            .Cells(31, 7).Value = "VSKO"
            .Cells(31, 4).Value = departmentHead(n)
...
Else
            .Cells(14, 7).Value = ""
            .Cells(31, 7).Value = ""
            .Cells(31, 4).Value = ""
End If
```

Comment: Thx for everyone. I am going to use the little elegant Select Case method.
Nesting IF conditional statement was not intended. Now, after my first SOF post, I know it is worth to get thoroughly my code with clear head once again after error message recieval. And post only hardcore ones.

Answer (score 3):

> *As the code has been inserted, tabulators got wrong. Do not bother with that.*

And yet, running your code through an [indenter](http://rubberduckvba.com/Indentation) (disclaimer: that's the Rubberduck Smart Indenter port; Rubberduck being a free & open-source VBIDE add-in project I manage) gives a major clue about what's going on:

```
If departmentHead(n) = "Name1" Then
    .Cells(14, 7).Value = "VIO"
    .Cells(31, 7).Value = "VIO"
    .Cells(31, 4).Value = departmentHead(n)
    If departmentHead(n) = "Name2" Then
        .Cells(14, 7).Value = "ITO"
        .Cells(31, 7).Value = "ITO"
        .Cells(31, 4).Value = departmentHead(n)
        If departmentHead(n) = "Name3" Then
            .Cells(14, 7).Value = "VSKO"
            .Cells(31, 7).Value = "VSKO"
            .Cells(31, 4).Value = departmentHead(n)
            If departmentHead(n) = "Name4" Then
                .Cells(14, 7).Value = "AMO"
                .Cells(31, 7).Value = "AMO"
                .Cells(31, 4).Value = departmentHead(n)
                If departmentHead(n) = "Name5" Then
                    .Cells(14, 7).Value = "NUO"
                    .Cells(31, 7).Value = "NUO"
                    .Cells(31, 4).Value = departmentHead(n)
                    If departmentHead(n) = "Name6" Then
                        .Cells(14, 7).Value = "KGO"
                        .Cells(31, 7).Value = "KGO"
                        .Cells(31, 4).Value = departmentHead(n)
                        If departmentHead(n) = "Name7" Then
                            .Cells(14, 7).Value = "PGO"
                            .Cells(31, 7).Value = "PGO"
                            .Cells(31, 4).Value = departmentHead(n)
                            If departmentHead(n) = "Name8" Then
                                .Cells(14, 7).Value = "ETO"
                                .Cells(31, 7).Value = "ETO"
                                .Cells(31, 4).Value = departmentHead(n)
                                If departmentHead(n) = "Name9" Then
                                    .Cells(14, 7).Value = "GMDO"
                                    .Cells(31, 7).Value = "GMDO"
                                    .Cells(31, 4).Value = departmentHead(n)
                                    If departmentHead(n) = "Name10" Then
                                        .Cells(14, 7).Value = "ABO"
                                        .Cells(31, 7).Value = "ABO"
                                        .Cells(31, 4).Value = departmentHead(n)
                                    Else
                                        .Cells(14, 7).Value = ""
                                        .Cells(31, 7).Value = ""
                                        .Cells(31, 4).Value = ""
```

All these `If` blocks are actually **nested**, because they're never terminated with an `End If` token. So when the compiler reaches an `End With` token, it doesn't know what to line it up against, because it's still expecting to close the inner-most `If` block.

---

Rule of thumb, when you have repeated conditionals all evaluating the same value, you want a `Select...Case` block - also consider reducing the redundancies by extracting the changing string value into its own local variable:

```
Dim result As String
Select Case departmentHead(n)
    Case "Name1"
        result = "VIO"
    Case "Name2"
        result = "ITO"
    Case "Name3"
        result = "VSKO"
    '...
End Select

.Cells(14, 7).Value = result
.Cells(31, 7).Value = result
If result <> vbNullString Then .Cells(31, 4) = departmentHead(n)
```

Comment: That webpage is quite something... Super useful!

Comment: @TimStack indeed! wait until you try the (free & open-source) VBIDE add-in it's for!